# How to slice date string before parsing it to datetime-local input

Tags: html, angular, date

I want to edit or change date of a json object but because of the long milliseconds string, the datetime-local could not display the date. Is there a way to first remove three(3) numbers from the milliseconds string before I parse the date string to form input.

**json**

```
{
"appointment": "Dentist",
"date": "2007-04-30 13:10:02.047438"
}
```

**comp.ts**

```
showDetail(data: any) {
   this.formData.controls.appointment.setValue( data.appointment );
   this.formData.controls.date.setValue( data.date );  //here the datetime-local could not read .000000 millis, I need to remove last 000
}
```

**.html**

```
    //....
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Date:</label> <input type="datetime-local"
        value="2007-04-30T13:10:02" class="form-control"
        formControlName="date" required>
</div>
```

I have in the DB e.g **2007-04-30 13:10:02.047438** but I want to slice to **2007-04-30 13:10:02.047** in my .ts file, so that my form can display the date when showDetails function is called.

Comment: use https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substr() like so:

```
    let str = "2007-04-30 13:10:02.047a438";
    str.substr(0, str.length-3);
```

Here's the matching [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid trimming the length a better approach would be using Angular Date Pipe filter. you can display in various formats as per your choice. you can check it out here [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)